# Pytorch loss.backward() gives none grad for parameters of Rx, Ry Gate

Tags: python, pytorch, qml, quantum-computing, autograd

I'm trying to train parameters `params` by performing linear Transformation on an input tensor `x` by matrix multiplying Rx to input followed by Ry matrix to their result. (each matrix Rx and Ry have a parameter `params[i]` each that define the matrix).

then I calculate loss by mse of `y` and the predicted output. when I do `loss.backward()`
Im getting `params.grad`  as None.

```
import torch

def get_device(gpu_no):
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        return torch.device('cuda', gpu_no)
    else:
        return torch.device('cpu')


device = get_device(0)

params = torch.tensor(([[0.011], [0.012]]), requires_grad=True).to(device).to(torch.cfloat)


x_gate = torch.tensor([[1., 0.], [0., 1.]]).to(device)
y_gate = torch.tensor(([[0, -1j], [1j, 0]])).to(device)


def rx(theta):
    # co = torch.cos(theta / 2)
    # si = torch.sin(theta / 2)
    # Rx_gate = torch.stack([torch.cat([co, -si], dim=-1),
    #                       torch.cat([-si, co], dim=-1)], dim=-2).squeeze(0).to(device).to(torch.cfloat).requires_grad_()
    # Rx_gate = torch.exp(-1j * (theta / 2) * x_gate).to(device).to(torch.cfloat).requires_grad_()
    Rx_gate = torch.tensor(([[torch.cos(theta/2), -torch.sin(theta/2)],
                             [-torch.sin(theta/2), torch.cos(theta/2)]]), requires_grad=True).to(device).to(torch.cfloat)

    return Rx_gate


def ry(theta):
    # co = torch.cos(theta / 2)
    # si = torch.sin(theta / 2)
    # Ry_gate = torch.stack([torch.cat([co, -si]),
    #                             torch.cat([si, co])], dim=-2).squeeze(0).to(device).to(torch.cfloat).requires_grad_()
    # Ry_gate = torch.exp(-1j * (theta / 2) * y_gate).to(device).to(torch.cfloat).requires_grad_()
    Ry_gate = torch.tensor(([[torch.cos(theta / 2), -torch.sin(theta / 2)],
                        [torch.sin(theta / 2), torch.cos(theta / 2)]]), requires_grad=True).to(device).to(torch.cfloat)

    return Ry_gate


x = torch.tensor([1., 0.]).to(device).to(torch.cfloat)
y = torch.tensor([0., 1.]).to(device).to(torch.cfloat)


def pred(params):
    out = rx(params[0]) @ x
    out = ry(params[1]) @ out
    return out

print("params        :", params)
print("prediction    :", pred(params))

loss = torch.pow((y - pred(params)), 2).sum()
print("loss          :", loss)

loss.backward()
print("loss grad     :", loss.grad)
print("params grad   :", params.grad)
```

my output is

```
params        : tensor([[0.0110+0.j],
        [0.0120+0.j]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ToCopyBackward0>)
prediction    : tensor([1.0000e+00+0.j, 5.0000e-04+0.j], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<MvBackward0>)
loss          : tensor(1.9990+1.7485e-07j, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
loss grad     : None
params grad   : None
```

why grad is none even though params has `grad_fn=<ToCopyBackward0>`.
Also i get this warning:

```
 UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the .grad field to be populated for a non-leaf Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead. See github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531 for more informations. (Triggered internally at  aten\src\ATen/core/TensorBody.h:417.)
```

return self._grad

Answer (score 1):

Good observation, you indeed have a correct backpropagation of the gradient through the gradient. So why are you getting none when accessing your parameter?

---

The reason why you can't access the gradient of this parameter is that only leaf tensors have their gradient cached in memory. Here, since `params` is a copy of a leaf-tensor (you called `to` twice on it which made that happen), it will not be considered a gradient of the computation graph.

In order to get access to the gradient of that parameter at runtime, you can force the engine to cache and make it accessible outside with a simple call to [`retain_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.retain_grad.html) as suggested by the warning message.

```
params.retain_grad()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I replaced my code so that I'm not using `.to()` at all. And for Rx, Ry matrix I'm not using a `torch.tensor()` as I read somewhere that it detaches the variable from the graph. My new code runs with grad now and I can train the Linear Transformation matrices Rx and Ry

Answer (score 1):

I replaced my code so that I'm not using `.to()` at all. And for Rx, Ry matrix I'm not using a `torch.tensor()` as I read somewhere that it detaches the variable from the graph. My new code runs with grad now and I can train the Linear Transformation matrices Rx and Ry. Thanks for the above answer for clarifying

This is my new code. Runs smooth like butter:

```
import torch

def get_device(gpu_no):
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        return torch.device('cuda', gpu_no)
    else:
        return torch.device('cpu')


device = get_device(0)

params = torch.tensor(([[0.011], [0.012]]), requires_grad=True, device=device, dtype=torch.cfloat)


x_gate = torch.tensor([[1., 0.], [0., 1.]], device=device, dtype=torch.cfloat)
y_gate = torch.tensor([[0, -1j], [1j, 0]], device=device, dtype=torch.cfloat)


def rx(theta):
    co = torch.cos(theta / 2)
    si = torch.sin(theta / 2)
    Rx_gate = torch.stack([torch.cat([co, -si], dim=-1),
                          torch.cat([-si, co], dim=-1)], dim=-2).squeeze(0)
    # Rx_gate = torch.exp(1j *  x_gate* (theta / 2))

    # print(" Rx_gate e", Rx_gate)
    # Rx_gate = torch.tensor(([[torch.cos(theta/2), -torch.sin(theta/2)],
    #                          [-torch.sin(theta/2), torch.cos(theta/2)]]), requires_grad=True, device=device, dtype=torch.cfloat)

    return Rx_gate


def ry(theta):
    co = torch.cos(theta / 2)
    si = torch.sin(theta / 2)
    Ry_gate = torch.stack([torch.cat([co, -si]),
                                torch.cat([si, co])], dim=-2).squeeze(0)
    # Ry_gate = torch.exp(1j * y_gate * (theta / 2))
    # Ry_gate = torch.tensor(([[torch.cos(theta / 2), -torch.sin(theta / 2)],
    #                     [torch.sin(theta / 2), torch.cos(theta / 2)]]), requires_grad=True, device=device, dtype=torch.cfloat)

    return Ry_gate


x = torch.tensor([1., 0.], device=device, dtype=torch.cfloat)
y = torch.tensor([0., 1.], device=device, dtype=torch.cfloat)


def pred(params):
    out = rx(params[0]) @ x
    out = ry(params[1]) @ out
    return out

print("params        :", params)
print("prediction    :", pred(params))

loss = torch.pow((y - pred(params)), 2).sum()
print("loss          :", loss)

loss.backward()

print("params grad   :", params.grad)
```

Output:

```
params        : tensor([[0.0110+0.j],
        [0.0120+0.j]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
prediction    : tensor([1.0000e+00+0.j, 5.0000e-04+0.j], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<MvBackward0>)
loss          : tensor(1.9990+1.7485e-07j, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
params grad   : tensor([[ 1.0000+0.j],
        [-1.0000+0.j]], device='cuda:0')
```